# Android not starting other activity

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to Android programming, but i have never encountered this problem before. When i click the button, the emulator is just not doing anything, when it's supposed to start another activity. Here's my intent within the button:

```
public class StartScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bStartQuiz:
            Intent a = new Intent(StartScreen.this, QuizMenu.class);
            startActivity(a);   
        break;
```

Here follows some more cases which are not defined yet.
onCreate method from the class i try to start:

```
public class QuizMenu extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categories);
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.ultimatequiz.StartScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ultimatequiz.QuizMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ultimatequiz.QuizMenu" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What i really don't understand is that i get no errors in the log. It's just not "responding", but the button do change into state_pressed.

Comment: Which i have done for many hours.

Comment: Is listener activated properly? try to put log in case statement and check whether control is reaching in case statement or not

Comment: As you are using eclipse why not put a break point and run your android app inn debug mode.

Comment: Put a break point and run your program, unresponsive means you are doing heavy work in the UI thread. do you set up DB connection?

Comment: Please edit your question to show more code from StartScreen, specifically how you are registering the onClick listener for the button since there is nothing obviously wrong with the code shown.

Comment: I have updated the code. The break has always been there.

Comment: are you sure you set onClickListener for button

Comment: absolutely sure, you can see the whole onClick method now, despite for the other undefined buttons.

Comment: You dont have a button is set to start new Activity. What is R.id.bStartQuiz? Is it a button?

Comment: Did you call this onclick method  In xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to open a new activity by clicking a `Button`. Then all you have to do is to have a `Button` in your `activity_start_screen.xml`:

```
<Button
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/your_button"/>
```

After that you have to add this in your `StartScreen`:

```
public class StartScreen extends Activity {
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(StartScreen.this,QuizMenu.class);
            StartScreen.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

        }
    });
```

and only this in your `manifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.ultimatequiz.StartScreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.ultimatequiz.QuizMenu"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if your case works well.Try this.

```
public class StartScreen extends Activity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);

            Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent a = new Intent(StartScreen.this, QuizMenu.class);
                    startActivity(a);

                }
            });
        }
```

}

I always use this way, I find it easy to handle.

if you got your layout defined onlick delete it

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a function for it :

```
public static void LaunchIntent(){
        Intent a = new Intent(StartScreen.this, QuizMenu.class);
        startActivity(a);
```

and in the click listener call the function :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.bStartQuiz:
        LaunchIntent();
    break;
}
```